# Pylint: How do I cleanly suppress things without subsequent 'suppressed-message' nonsense?

Tags: python, pylint

I have a file foo.py that makes extensive use of the Faker third-party module. As such, pylint generates a lot of 'no-member' errors.

I would like to disable these in foo.py. So at the top, I tried
inserting:

```
# pragma pylint: disable=no-member
```

But, in a quite-annoying fashion, pylint now spits out a suppressed message every time it hits one of these errors - completely defeating the purpose of my pragma??

```
foo.py:1:0: I0011: Locally disabling no-member (E1101) (locally-disabled)
... other misc stuff ...
foo.py:177:0: I0020: Suppressed 'no-member' (from line 1) (suppressed-message)
foo.py:83:0: I0020: Suppressed 'no-member' (from line 1) (suppressed-message)
foo.py:85:0: I0020: Suppressed 'no-member' (from line 1) (suppressed-message)
```

Huh... well that's... ridiculous.

So I tried to... suppress the suppression messages??

```
# pragma pylint: disable=no-member,suppressed-message
```

And THEN it gets even better...

```
foo.py:1:0: I0011: Locally disabling no-member (E1101) (locally-disabled)
foo.py:1:0: I0011: Locally disabling suppressed-message (I0020) (locally-disabled)
foo.py:1:0: C0102: Black listed name "foo" (blacklisted-name)
.... misc stuff, actual things I should clean up here ...
foo.py:1:0: I0021: Useless suppression of 'suppressed-message' (useless-suppression)
```

So I guess my question is - how do I make suppression messages go away entirely on a per-file basis, without some annoying replacement message being dropped in?

EDIT: Thank you for the comments.

Output of pylint --version:

```
pylint 2.1.1
astroid 2.0.4
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:23:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)]
```

Comment: `Useless suppression of 'suppressed-message' (useless-suppression)` ...hilarious!

Comment: What's your Pylint version? Have you tried updating it? [I0020 and I0021 are supposed to be suppressed by default.](https://www.logilab.org/110908)

Comment: Resistance is futile, your suppression will be suppressed.

Comment: If your Pylint is up to date, you may have accidentally configured it to unsuppress those messages.

Comment: @user2357112 In my pylintrc in the MESSAGES CONTROL section, I'm first doing an enable=all  followed by a disable=<item 1>, <item2>

Think this is the problem? Maybe there's something I'm not understanding about how the config file is working in conjunction with the file-level pragama directive?

Comment: Yep, that'd do it.

Comment: I recommend this method of configuring pylint: `pip uninstall -y pylint`  (it has never bugged me since)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. I added 'suppressed-message' to the disabled list in the config file. If you don't see any hidden gotchyas' in that approach, I'll self-answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I-category messages are disabled by default. You turned them on yourself, by setting `enable=all` in the `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` section of your pylintrc, and then you didn't disable them in the `disable` list in the same section. Add `suppressed-message` to the `disable` list in your pylintrc, and the suppressed-message messages should stop appearing.

As for the useless-suppression message, that seems to be a pylint bug.